# How to secure you api URL from BurpSuite checking?

Tags: security, web, burp

Actually this is not a code problem but security problem.

I've got an email from stranger that contain about what he's done to my website.

I don't how he do it but there are proof showing he can get the api and the parameter when clicking button by burpSuite apps

is there anyway to protect website from this checking ?

Answer (score 0):

Please prevent CRSS attack. Can follow the link- https://brightsec.com/blog/cross-site-scirpting-prevention/

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> is existed already

Comment: Then you can try with burp suite testing your project security and find the flaws, you will get specific error there. Then you can solve that.

Comment: Recently i installed the BurpSuite. Try to intercept my own website, but there is no list of API shown like the stranger done. It's only show list of controller and function name called. Am i miss something ?

Comment: You can try to check API link verification from BurpSuite, then you may get something.